# add remove class in resize window using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this jQuery code for `add` `remove` class using `jQuery` in resize window:

JS:

```
$(function () {

    $(window).bind("resize", function () {
        console.log($(this).width())
        if ($(this).width() < 500) {
            $('div').removeClass('yellow').addClass('red')
        } else {
            $('div').removeClass('red').addClass('yellow')
        }
    })
})
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width:300px; height:100px;" class="yellow"></div>
```

In action, This worked only when i manualy resize window But in default if device window < 500 this function not work.

how do fix this ?!

Demo [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6v7GE/)

Comment: Initial painting is a different Event then resize. You could extract the logic into a function and bind it to resize as well as document.ready.

Comment: Check my answer and fiddle in the below. It is the simplest way of doing that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to run function on page load

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

```
$(window).bind("resize", function () {
    console.log($(this).width())
    if ($(this).width() < 500) {
        $('div').removeClass('yellow').addClass('red')
    } else {
        $('div').removeClass('red').addClass('yellow')
    }
}).trigger('resize');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6v7GE/67/)

You can also use [CSS `media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) queries to set the style properties of elements on page load. This will have little performance gain and better user experience than using Javascript.

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    div {
        color: red;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    div {
        color: yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using media queries is a good option, but what if OP want to perform some other stuffs when window size is something? OP didn't ask for that but any how just wondering.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yes, that's why I've added both the approach, using Javascript and CSS

Answer (score 4):

Try to invoke the `resize` event once when the DOM got ready,

```
$(function(){
   $(window).bind("resize",function(){
    if($(this).width() <500){
      $('div').removeClass('yellow').addClass('red')
    }
    else{
      $('div').removeClass('red').addClass('yellow')
    }
   }).resize();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6v7GE/68/)

Answer (score 0):

Use media Query

Use the following Css

```
.yellow{
background:yellow;
}

@media (max-width:500px) {
    .yellow {
    background:red;
    }
}
```

Check the folowing fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/adxg3079/

Let me know if it is helpful